# How can I solve withdraw function not working on a deployed contract which worked on testnet

Tags: etherscan, erc-721, deployed-bytecode

This is my smart contract and the withdraw function doesn't work , throws a big gas fee amount and seems not to work

```js
        // SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
    pragma solidity ^0.8.9;
    
    import "erc721a/contracts/ERC721A.sol";
    import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
    import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";
    
    contract name is ERC721A , Ownable{
        using Strings for uint256;
    
        string private uriPrefix = "https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/-/";
        string public uriSuffix=".json";
        uint256 public cost = 0.005 ether;
        uint256 public maxSupply = 317;
        uint256 public maxMint = 5;
        uint256 public totalMaxMint = 5;
        uint256 public freeMaxMintAmount = 0;
        bool public paused = false;
        bool public publicSale = true;
        
        mapping(address => uint256) public addressMintedBalance;
    
        constructor () ERC721A("-", "-") {}
    
        modifier mintVerification(uint256 _mintAmount){
            if(msg.sender != owner()) {
                require(_mintAmount > 0 && _mintAmount <= maxMint, 'Invalid mint amount');
            }
            require(totalSupply() + _mintAmount <= maxSupply, 'Max Suppley exceeded!');
            _;
        }
    
        modifier mintPriceVerification(uint256 _mintAmount){
            uint256 ownerMintedCount = addressMintedBalance[msg.sender];
    
            if(ownerMintedCount >= freeMaxMintAmount){
                require(msg.value >= cost * _mintAmount, 'Insufficient funds!');
            }
            _;
        }
    
        function mint(uint256 _mintAmount) public payable mintVerification(_mintAmount) mintPriceVerification(_mintAmount) {
            require(!paused , 'The contract is paused');
            require(publicSale, "Not open to public yet");
            uint256 ownerMintedCount = addressMintedBalance[msg.sender];
    
            if(ownerMintedCount < freeMaxMintAmount) {
                require(ownerMintedCount + _mintAmount <= freeMaxMintAmount, "Exceeded Free Mint Limit");
            } else if(ownerMintedCount >= freeMaxMintAmount){
                require(ownerMintedCount + _mintAmount <= totalMaxMint, "Exceeded Mint Limit");
            }
    
            _safeMint(msg.sender, _mintAmount);
            for (uint256 i = 1; i <= _mintAmount; i++){
                addressMintedBalance[msg.sender]++;
            }
        }
    
        function ownerMint(uint256 _mintAmount) public payable onlyOwner{
            require(_mintAmount > 0 , "Invalid mint amount!");
            require(totalSupply() + _mintAmount <= maxSupply, "Max supply exceeded");
            _safeMint(msg.sender, _mintAmount);
        }
        
    
        function mintForAddress(uint256 _mintAmount, address _receiver) public mintVerification(_mintAmount) onlyOwner {
            _safeMint(_receiver, _mintAmount);
        }
    
        function _startTokenId() internal view virtual override returns (uint256) {
            return 1;
        }
    
        function tokenURI(uint256 _tokenId) public view virtual override returns (string memory) {
            require(_exists(_tokenId), 'ERC721Metadata: URI query for nonexistent token');
    
            string memory currentBaseURI = _baseURI();
            return bytes(currentBaseURI).length > 0
                ? string(abi.encodePacked(currentBaseURI, _tokenId.toString(), uriSuffix))
                : '';
        }
    
        function setFreeMax(uint256 _amount) public onlyOwner{
            freeMaxMintAmount = _amount;
        }
        
        function setCost(uint256 _cost) public onlyOwner{
            cost = _cost;
        }
    
        function setTotalMintMax(uint256 _amount) public onlyOwner{
            maxMint = _amount;
        }
    
        function setUriPreffix(string memory _uriPreffix) public onlyOwner{
            uriPrefix = _uriPreffix;
        }
    
        function setUriSuffix(string memory _uriSuffix) public onlyOwner{
            uriSuffix = _uriSuffix;
        }
    
        function setPaused(bool _state) public onlyOwner{
            paused = _state;
        }
    
        function setPublicSale(bool _state) public onlyOwner{
            publicSale = _state;
        }
    
        function withdraw() public payable onlyOwner {
      
            (bool os, ) = payable(owner()).call{value: address(this).balance}(""); 
            require(os);
       
        }
    
        function _baseURI() internal view virtual override returns (string memory) {
            return uriPrefix;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The `withdraw` function is `payable`, which means that you cannot send a 0 eth balance to it. Are you sending some eth to it while calling it? I'm not sure why you declared it as `payable` since anyways only the owner can call it and it will return all the balance of the contract to the owner anyways. But yes, send a couple of `wei`s while calling it and it should work.

Comment: @JeremyThen when you have a payable function it doesn't mean that you must send funds, it means that you can do it, so you could send a transaction with zero eth to a payable funcion with no problem and it will work unless it is explicitly rejected by your code

Comment: agreed that it doesn't seem to make much sense to have a payable withdraw function, but that doesn't mean that funds have to be sent to call it

Comment: Does the account have enough gas to pay for the transaction? Also check if the owner() is capable of receiving ether for the case of it being a contract.

Answer (score 0):

Metamask will throw a gas error if it suspects the transaction will fail. In the case of your withdraw function it could be because you are calling the function with an address that is not the owner.